# Get selected options of a simple which belongs to a configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I have a product object of a simple product which belongs to a configurable. I'm trying to get the attributes of the configurable which led to the simple I have. Since each simple of a configurable is the result of selecting options of that configurable, that should be possible.

I have the full simple product option and [can easily get the Option value and Label](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/146175/77979) of the attribute but only if I know the name of the attribute. Since the attribute is dynamic and can change I won't hardcode it.

There's a [similar question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/123538/77979) for Magento 1 but that won't work for Magento 2.

How do I get the configurable options that led to the simple I have available?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up resolving the parent product and mapping the configurable attributes from the parent to the ones the simple product has:

```php
class ConfigurableAttributes implements ArgumentInterface
{
    private Configurable $configurable;
    private ProductRepository $productRepo;

    public function __construct(
        Configurable $configurable,
        ProductRepository $productRepo
    ) {
        $this->configurable = $configurable;
        $this->productRepo = $productRepo;
    }

    public function getConfigurableAttributes(Product $product): array
    {
        $parentId = $this->configurable->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());

        if (count($parentId) === 0) {
            return [];
        }

        $parent = $this->productRepo->getById($parentId[0]);

        $attributes = $this->configurable->getConfigurableAttributes($parent);

        $resolvedAttributes = [];
        foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
            $attributeCode = $attribute->getProductAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
            $resolvedAttributes[$attributeCode] = [
                'label' => $attribute->getLabel(),
                'value' => $product->getAttributeText($attributeCode),
            ];
        }

        return $resolvedAttributes;
    }
}
```

This works but I feel like it adds too much unnecessary overhead because now I need to load the full product every time I want to get the configurable options.